# Ignoring Referenced Objects on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application that can generate several orders. On the first run this works pretty well, but when i create the second order and try to save it to the database i get an error that an object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.

I suspect this is not because of the newly created order-object but because of the held references. But even then, given that the merge-option is AppendOnly, these attached objects should be ignored on the SaveChanges() call.

The code for the generation of the order objects goes as follows:

```
public void GenerateOrder(){
    Order order = new Order();
    order.Items.Add(item1);
    order.Items.Add(item2);
}

public void AddOrder(Order order){
    _context.Orders.Add(order);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code? It's a little hard to diagnose what's going wrong in your program without seeing the code for myself

Comment: attaching should only be done with objects that already exist in the database, otherwise you should add them.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: How do you create `item1` and `item2` - they might have keys that already exist.

Comment: Item1 and Item2 are pulled from a database and have definitley keys that already exists. But shouldn't AppendOnly take care of that. On top of that the first order is created without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved it now by clearing the cache of my context. I assume that the problem was caused by the fact that i am using a long lived context and therefore some of the objects weren't disposed properly.

```
public void ClearEntityCache(){
    _context.Dispose();
    _context = new EntityContext();
}
```